# What's the expected lifetime of a Firebase cloud notification token?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase messaging in my Android app. In the FirebaseMessagingService class, I override the "onNewToken" method. When I see a new token, I send it to my server, which later uses it to send notifications to the device (by posting the appropriate payload to https://fcm.googleapis.com).

More often than I expected, the notification post returns a 404 error along with a message "Requested entity was not found". When this happens I remove that token from my database. I expected this could happen occasionally, but I'm seeing it every day. Most of them do succeed, however.

Are these tokens meant to be temporary? Should I be seeing them fail this frequently? When I get that 404 error, should I be deleting the token entirely or should I retain it and retry it later?

Comment: I'm not sure what call is returning a 404. Can you show the code for that?

Comment: The 404 is a response to an http request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-name/messages:send. I'd rather not give any code because it is a sensitive medical application, but the code doesn't really matter, it's just standard Java code for making http requests. Since it works most of the time I don't think the code is the issue.